# How to create converters for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read in a CSV file with pandas. Two columns are to be multiplied by a different constant each.

```
params = {
    "table-columns": ['A', 'B'],
    "multiplicands": ['0.001', '0.000001']
}

converters_ = {}
for i in range(0,len(params['table-columns'])):
    column = params['table-columns'][i]
    multiplicand = params['multiplicands'][i]
    display(column + '/' + multiplicand)
    func = lambda x: float(x) * float(multiplicand)
    converters_[column] = func
display(converters_['A'](1)) # should be 1e-03
display(converters_['B'](1)) # should be 1e-06

#df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters=converters_)
```

This is the output:

```
'A/0.001'
'B/0.000001'
1e-06
1e-06
```

Column A should be multiplied by 0.001, but it is multiplied by 0.000001. Where is the bug here?

Comment: Could you please clarify why you are using lambda function inside the loop and not just directly multiplying x and multiplicand?

Comment: Please check these posts for more details on lambda function inside a loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture and https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `func`, which you've stored in converters_[0] and converters_[1], does not evaluate `multiplicand` until you actually call `func`, at which point `multiplicand` is "0.000001".

You can try replacing the assignment to `func` with this call to `eval()` which hardcodes the value of `multiplicand` into the body of the lambda:

```py
    func = eval(f"lambda x: float(x) * {float(multiplicand)}")
```

Output:

```
A/0.001
B/0.000001
0.001
1e-06
```